# Using html in JOINTJS elements does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jointjs

I have tried to use code from the example: http://www.jointjs.com/tutorial/html-elements but it doesn't work properly. I just got a connection line, without any rects.
My HTML:

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/joint.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
</head>

<body>
 <div id="paper"></div>
 <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/lodash.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/backbone.min.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/joint.js"></script>
 <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in version of joint.js. They use 0.9.3 in example while current version is 0.9.5.